# Want to iterate through dictionary with dynamic keys in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have dictionaries within a dictionary with specific keys. Now I want to access each key in the template dynamically. I want to use main keys as subheadings within a table and show the data of that related keys under those subheadings.

I have tried the below code but it isn't working.

Error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /daily/report
Could not parse the remainder: '{{ledger}}' from 'ledgers.{{ledger}}
```

How can I accomplish this?

My View:

```
@login_required
def accounts_report(request):
    credit_vouchers = CreditVoucher.objects.all()
    debit_vouchers = DebitVoucher.objects.all()
    heads = AccountHead.objects.all()
    opening_balance = request.GET.get('balance')
    balance = float(opening_balance)
    date_from = request.GET.get('from')
    date_to = request.GET.get('to')
    credit_vouchers = credit_vouchers.filter(date__gte=date_from, date__lte=date_to)
    debit_vouchers = debit_vouchers.filter(date__gte=date_from, date__lte=date_to)

    ledgers = {}
    for head in heads:
        key = head.head_name
        ledgers.setdefault(key, [])

    for item in ledgers:
        key = item
        ledgers.setdefault(key, [])
        a_head = AccountHead.objects.get(head_name=key)
        d_vouchers = debit_vouchers.filter(account_head=a_head)
        c_vouchers = credit_vouchers.filter(account_head=a_head)
        for voucher in d_vouchers:
            balance -= voucher.amount
            ledgers[key].append({
                'date': voucher.date,
                'description': voucher.description,
                'voucher_no': voucher.voucher_serial,
                'debit_amount': voucher.amount,
                'credit_amount': 0,
                'balance': balance,
            })
        for voucher in c_vouchers:
            balance += voucher.amount
            ledgers[key].append({
                'date': voucher.date,
                'description': voucher.description,
                'voucher_no': voucher.voucher_serial,
                'debit_amount': 0,
                'credit_amount': voucher.amount,
                'balance': balance,
            })

    context = {
        'heads': heads,
        'opening_balance': opening_balance,
        'ledgers': ledgers
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/report.html', context=context)
```

Template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table.center {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Voucher No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Debit</th>
        <th>Credit</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Opening Balance</td>
        <td>{{opening_balance}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for ledger in ledgers %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">{{ledger}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% for item in ledgers.{{ledger}} %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.voucher_no}}</td>
            <td>{{item.date}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.debit_amount}}</td>
            <td>{{item.credit_amount}}</td>
            <td>{{item.balance}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to use dynamic keys in a Django template is to write [a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

You can create a `get_dictionnary_item.py` in your `templatetags` folder :

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_dictionary_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

Then you can use it in your template:

```
{% load get_dictionary_item %}
...
{{ ledgers|get_dictionary_item:ledger }}
```

Comment: @MdMoksedulAlam I'm glad I could have helped! Could you please mark the question as answered by upvoting this answer and marking it as correct? You can have more explanations about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry, Mickael Martinez, My reputation is too low to cast votes, cause I am new here, I will vote it after achieving the minimum reputation for casting votes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

replace `ledgers.{{ledger}}` with just `ledger`

```
{% for ledger in ledgers %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">{{ledger}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% for item in ledger %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.voucher_no}}</td>
                <td>{{item.date}}</td>
                <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                <td>{{item.debit_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{item.credit_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{item.balance}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: this only iterates through the characters of the main key, I want to iterate through the data under the main key